# Sending only storage requests to gcs using gcs connector through proxy

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to use Envoy proxy to route requests to GCS. I am able to route the actual storage requests using through proxy. But when I set this `fs.gs.proxy.address` parameter in GCS connector settings, OAuth token generation requests fail.

Is there any way to disable OAuth requests and let them go directly to the server?

Answer (score 1):

GCS connector has a global proxy settings for all requests (storage and OAuth), so you need to configure your proxy server to also pass through OAuth request.

It is not possible to completely disable OAuth in GCS Connector.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. GCS connector uses https. So when I use Envoy proxy it doesn't work as there some issue in CONECT call handshake. Is there any way to disable the client side SSL atleast? @Igor Dvorzhak